# knp-paginator - paginating to top of section rather than top of page

Tags: knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

I have a section in my html twig page where I'm using knp paginator to paginate a query. It works fine except that when I click on the pagination link I would like to move to the top of the section rather than jumping to the top of the page.
I've tried several ways to solve the issue inlcuding using Stimulus with Symfony but I always jump to the top of my page rather than the top of my section with section ID.

Any idea how I could solve this relatively simple issue? Is there for instance a php file where I could change the slug of the page, instead of navigating to ?page=3, I would navigate to ?page=3/#section1...

Thank you.